# Is there a more concise way to have a background image with a certain opacity and then have a hover effect than how i have written it?

Tags: css, html

Basically, I built this wedding photo website, and it does what I want it to, but just for learning sakes, I wanted to know if there is a way to shorten my code because it looks redundant.

This is what I have right now that I think can be improved, I basically have this repeating for 9 photos. Also for some reason (there is a total of 33 photos) when I add more than 12 photos to the page some of them are just empty blocks, so i removed that numbered photo and what ever moves to its place also becomes empty so its not a case of the photo not working correctly.

```
.image {
    height: 300px;
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin: 1.66%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}

.image1 {
    background-image: url("Photo1.jpg");

}

.image2 {
    background-image: url("Photo2.jpg");
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.image2:hover {
    background-image: url("Photo2.jpg");
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

Like I said it works, but it is slow for one, which im not certain why, and because it is pretty long.

here is the html code since it was requested

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Scobee/Feistner Wedding</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="weddingSite.css">
</head>

<body>
    <p><em>Scobee/Feistner Wedding</em></p>

    <div class="image image1"></div>
    <div class="image image2"></div>
    <div class="image image3"></div>
    <div class="image image4"></div>
    <div class="image image5"></div>
    <div class="image image6"></div>
    <div class="image image7"></div>
    <div class="image image8"></div>
    <div class="image image9"></div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please add you html code also

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on another stack exchange site like code review

Answer (score 0):

You only need to declare once if you are using pseudo selectors (:hide).  You could do this.

```
.image2 {
    background-image: url("Photo2.jpg");
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.image2:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

Removes the declaration background-image: url("Photo2.jpg"); on hover event.